# A multi-dimensional array insert and update into the database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a multiple select drop down box that produces me an array like this:

```
 array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "6" [2]=> string(1) "7" }
```

What I cannot work out is how to get the multiple select drop down box to insert update and select from or into the database.  I seem to only be getting one value

My current code situation is this -> And what the above `var_dump` is of:

```
SELECT * FROM {table} WHERE canid=? AND categoryid=?", array($emailCheck['id'], $fields['Occupation'][0]));
```

**Update Statement:** How could I implode this?

```
UPDATE {table} SET canid=?, categoryid=? WHERE canid=? AND categoryid=?", array($emailCheck['id'], implode(',', $fields['Occupation']));
```

My DB Structure is:

[image]

Comment: This depends on your database schema. I suggest you post that.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary Done but still unsure about the update/insert statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understood correctly and `$fields['Occupation']` contains multiple selected values from dropdown, then use `AND categoryid IN (?)` and use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to merge array into string like this: `implode(',', $fields['Occupation'])`

The complete code will look like this:

```
myFunction("SELECT * FROM {table} WHERE canid=? AND categoryid IN (?)", array($emailCheck['id'], implode(',', $fields['Occupation'])));
```

**UPDATE**

I think in this case, when you need to change these columns for each row independently, it would be better to loop over array in PHP and make separate queries:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($fields['Occupation']); $i++) {
    $id = $fields['Occupation'][$i];
    // here make query like before
    myFunction("UPDATE {table} SET canid=?, categoryid=? WHERE canid=? AND categoryid=?", array($emailCheck['id'], $id));
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  How would I do my update/insert statements?  I have updated my question with my update statement,  I am getting http://d.pr/i/Y5y7

Comment: it depends what you want to do in update/insert statement, I mean what values should be set to `canid=?, categoryid=?`. sorry for late reply

Comment: No problem im not well so hence why I am struggling.  canid = given by the database this works fine but all I am doing is basically saying if the cat id is found with the user  can id then do no reenter this information but update it.  If the can id was not found then insert. I need one canid catid per row

Comment: sorry, I was at work... if you have to change canid and catid per row, I think better would be to loop over array and make separate queries

Comment: wait can we just do the insert statement but I need to check if there is no double ups - from previous entries with that id

Comment: Thanks,  It seems to be only returning one value again

Answer (score 0):

you have to dynamically generate the parameter placeholder for each value

```
$params = array_merge(array($emailCheck['id']), $fields['Occupation']);
$catPlaceholders = '?'.str_repeat(',?',count($fields['Occupation'])-1);

myFunction("SELECT * FROM {table} WHERE canid=? AND categoryid IN ("
        .$catPlaceholders.")", $params);
```